# How do I change the Javascript src file on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Within my body tag, I have this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=ABQIAAkh87y8Hjhg76ty" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is it possible to add JavaScript or jQuery in the head of the page to change the "key" parameter in the script source. I am trying to do this before the render reaches the above tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the `src` attribute *before* the render reaches the tag, because modern browsers will download and parse the script as soon as it reaches a script tag (in that particular format).

You can use the `defer` attribute to hold off execution of the script until after the DOM has completely loaded, but this attribute is only supported in IE 4+ and Firefox 3.5+.

Answer (score 1):

why not dynamically create the script tag triggered by onload.

In onload: make the JQuery call, create the src url from the result, append the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that you could change the key parameter before that script is rendered but you could dynamically write the entire script tag like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.setAttribute('src', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key='
                     + param_ssKey + '/');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
```